# Command \mobile in \cvitem doesn't appear - ModernCV template

Tags: symbols, moderncv, cv, fontawesome

I'm trying to insert the mobile symbol in the `\cvitem` of the [ModernCV template](http://www.latextemplates.com/template/moderncv-cv-and-cover-letter), but I don't know how to do that. I tryed in different ways, but without any success.

```
\cvitem{\mobile}{123456} % error
\cvitem{\mobile{}}{123456} % the symbol doen't appear
```

Here an example:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{casual}
\moderncvcolor{blue} 
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\section{Personal Informations}
\cvitem{\mobile{}}{123456}

\end{document}
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Please make a compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that reproduces your problem. In the `moderncv` class personal infomation such as address, phone number and so on are usually added n the cv head.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that you are using an **very outdated version** of class `moderncv`: `Version 1.2 (25/3/16)`. The current one is version `2.0.0`!

This old version does not load package `fontawesome` you need to define your symbol `\mobilephonesymbol` ( I used the name used in current version, not your `\mobile` which is used for the personal informations in the header of `moderncv` 2.0.0):

```
\usepackage{fontawesome} % <============================================
\newcommand*{\mobilephonesymbol}   {{\Large\faMobile}~} % <=============
```

So you should add the two lines before to your preamble of your used overleaf file `cv_7.tex`.

Then your line

```
\cvitem{\mobilephonesymbol}{123456} % <=================================
```

can be executed as wished.

Please see the following complete mwe

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% "ModernCV" CV and Cover Letter
% LaTeX Template
% Version 1.2 (25/3/16)
%
% This template has been downloaded from:
% http://www.LaTeXTemplates.com
%
% Original author:
% Xavier Danaux (xdanaux@gmail.com) with modifications by:
% Vel (vel@latextemplates.com)
%
% License:
% CC BY-NC-SA 3.0 (http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/3.0/)
%
% Important note:
% This template requires the moderncv.cls and .sty files to be in the same 
% directory as this .tex file. These files provide the resume style and themes 
% used for structuring the document.
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PACKAGES AND OTHER DOCUMENT CONFIGURATIONS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv} % Font sizes: 10, 11, or 12; paper sizes: a4paper, letterpaper, a5paper, legalpaper, executivepaper or landscape; font families: sans or roman

\moderncvstyle{casual} % CV theme - options include: 'casual' (default), 'classic', 'oldstyle' and 'banking'
\moderncvcolor{blue} % CV color - options include: 'blue' (default), 'orange', 'green', 'red', 'purple', 'grey' and 'black'

\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry} % Reduce document margins
%\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3cm} % Uncomment to change the width of the dates column
%\setlength{\makecvtitlenamewidth}{10cm} % For the 'classic' style, uncomment to adjust the width of the space allocated to your name

\usepackage{fontawesome} % <============================================
\newcommand*{\mobilephonesymbol}   {{\Large\faMobile}~} % <=============

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   NAME AND CONTACT INFORMATION SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\firstname{John} % Your first name
\familyname{Smith} % Your last name

% All information in this block is optional, comment out any lines you don't need
\title{Curriculum Vitae}
%\address{123 Broadway}{City, State 12345}
%\mobile{(000) 111 1111}
%\phone{(000) 111 1112}
%\fax{(000) 111 1113}
%\email{john@smith.com}
%\homepage{staff.org.edu/~jsmith}{staff.org.edu/$\sim$jsmith} % The first argument is the url for the clickable link, the second argument is the url displayed in the template - this allows special characters to be displayed such as the tilde in this example
%\extrainfo{additional information}
%\photo[70pt][0.4pt]{pictures/picture} % The first bracket is the picture height, the second is the thickness of the frame around the picture (0pt for no frame)
%\quote{"A witty and playful quotation" - John Smith}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   COVER LETTER
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

% To remove the cover letter, comment out this entire block

%\clearpage
%
%\recipient{HR Department}{Corporation\\123 Pleasant Lane\\12345 City, State} % Letter recipient
%\date{\today} % Letter date
%\opening{Dear Sir or Madam,} % Opening greeting
%\closing{Sincerely yours,} % Closing phrase
%\enclosure[Attached]{curriculum vit\ae{}} % List of enclosed documents
%
%\makelettertitle % Print letter title
%
%\lipsum[1-3] % Dummy text
%
%\makeletterclosing % Print letter signature
%
%\newpage

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   CURRICULUM VITAE
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\makecvtitle % Print the CV title

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   EDUCATION SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{Personal Informations}

\cvitem{\mobilephonesymbol}{123456} % <=================================

\section{Education}

\cventry{2011--2012}{Masters of Commerce}{The University of California}{Berkeley}{\textit{GPA -- 8.0}}{First Class Honours}  % Arguments not required can be left empty
\cventry{2007--2010}{Bachelor of Business Studies}{The University of California}{Berkeley}{\textit{GPA -- 7.5}}{Specialized in Commerce}

\section{Masters Thesis}

\cvitem{Title}{\emph{Money Is The Root Of All Evil -- Or Is It?}}
\cvitem{Supervisors}{Professor James Smith \& Associate Professor Jane Smith}
\cvitem{Description}{This thesis explored the idea that money has been the cause of untold anguish and suffering in the world. I found that it has, in fact, not.}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   WORK EXPERIENCE SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{Experience}

\subsection{Vocational}

\cventry{2012--Present}{1\textsuperscript{st} Year Analyst}{\textsc{Lehman Brothers}}{Los Angeles}{}{Developed spreadsheets for risk analysis on exotic derivatives on a wide array of commodities (ags, oils, precious and base metals), managed blotter and secondary trades on structured notes, liaised with Middle Office, Sales and Structuring for bookkeeping.
\newline{}\newline{}
Detailed achievements:
\begin{itemize}
\item Learned how to make amazing coffee
\item Finally determined the reason for \textsc{PC LOAD LETTER}:
\begin{itemize}
\item Paper jam
\item Software issues:
\begin{itemize}
\item Word not sending the correct data to printer
\item Windows trying to print in letter format
\end{itemize}
\item Coffee spilled inside printer
\end{itemize}
\item Broke the office record for number of kitten pictures in cubicle
\end{itemize}}

%------------------------------------------------

\cventry{2010--2011}{Summer Intern}{\textsc{Lehman Brothers}}{Los Angeles}{}{Rated "truly distinctive" for Analytical Skills and Teamwork.}

%------------------------------------------------

\subsection{Miscellaneous}

\cventry{2008--2009}{Computer Repair Specialist}{Buy More}{Burbank}{}{Worked in the Nerd Herd and helped to solve computer problems by asking customers to turn their computers off and on again.}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   AWARDS SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{Awards}

\cvitem{2011}{School of Business Postgraduate Scholarship}
\cvitem{2010}{Top Achiever Award -- Commerce}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   COMPUTER SKILLS SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{Computer skills}

\cvitem{Basic}{\textsc{java}, Adobe Illustrator}
\cvitem{Intermediate}{\textsc{python}, \textsc{html}, \LaTeX, OpenOffice, Linux, Microsoft Windows}
\cvitem{Advanced}{Computer Hardware and Support}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   COMMUNICATION SKILLS SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{Communication Skills}

\cvitem{2010}{Oral Presentation at the California Business Conference}
\cvitem{2009}{Poster at the Annual Business Conference in Oregon}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   LANGUAGES SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{Languages}

\cvitemwithcomment{English}{Mothertongue}{}
\cvitemwithcomment{Spanish}{Intermediate}{Conversationally fluent}
\cvitemwithcomment{Dutch}{Basic}{Basic words and phrases only}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   INTERESTS SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{Interests}

\renewcommand{\listitemsymbol}{-~} % Changes the symbol used for lists

\cvlistdoubleitem{Piano}{Chess}
\cvlistdoubleitem{Cooking}{Dancing}
\cvlistitem{Running}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\end{document}
```

and its result without error messages:

[image: result with version 1.2.0]

At last I recommend to use the current version of class `moderncv` 2.0.0!

Answer (score 2):

The mobile phone symbol can be accessed via `\mobilephonesymbol` so maybe the following MWE produces what you want. I have also added a placeholder name as you example resulted in an error message about th missing name.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{casual}
\moderncvcolor{blue} 
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}

\name{John}{Doe}

\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\section{Personal Informations}
\cvitem{\mobilephonesymbol}{123456}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hello leandriis, thank you for your reply. Mycode is still wrong. See this please: http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=03378273371420717305

Comment: @GennaroArguzzi: Please don't post code (or other information) on external sites. The links to them might not work in the future and make the question unusable then. If you want to provide additional information, you can add it to your question using the `edit` button.